# How to make token logo appear consistently in Phantom?

Tags: metaplex, token, metadata, spl-token, phantom

I have created a token. The mint is a PDA, so I had to add the metadata from within the Rust code in my Program, calling Metaplex's MetadataProgram. This has been a long and rocky journey, but I finally got it done with the help of the awesome community.

The metadata is added correctly, see [here](https://explorer.solana.com/address/Ayx6751KcLP74dTdasP7B7wYxPgCQyMX4Lahdv4sMwNs/metadata).

HOWEVER, whether Phantom is showing the logo in in the wallet seems dependent on Phantom's current mood. When I open Phantom 10 times, maybe 1 or 2 times the logo/icon shows up. The other 8-9 times Phantom will show the name and symbol (which is great), but will show a `?` instead of the logo.

I minified the logo file to just 18KB. It is hosted on gitlab with CDN, which should give quick load times.

What can I do to have my logo show up **consistently**?

[image: This is how I want it ALL the time]

[image: This is how it shows up MOST of the time]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug on Phantom's side! We will triage this and keep you updated.

For others who find this post, Phantom prioritizes on-chain metadata that follows Metaplex's [Token Metadata Standard](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/). For `Fungible` tokens specifically, Phantom will look on-chain for `name` and `symbol` fields, as well as a `uri` field that points to additional off-chain JSON metadata. This off-chain JSON data should have an `image` field that Phantom will use to display the token's image.

In this specific case, your on-chain metadata correctly has a `uri` field that points to [valid JSON](https://okupub.gitlab.io/imgs/Oku.json). We will investigate why the `image` in that JSON is only displaying intermittently.

For more information, please see the [Displaying Tokens section of Phantom's developer docs](https://docs.phantom.app/best-practices/tokens).

Comment: Oh my. I hope we can get this fixed soon.

Comment: Have you heard of others having that issue as well?

Comment: I have not. We'll have to dig into why this is happening in this case.

Comment: may I ask what RPC node provider Phantom is using? We had a very similar issue with flip-flopping results when reading from an account. It turned it was QuickNode, and their support is just telling my dryly that some of their nodes are behind. After switching RPC providers, the problem was gone.